# How do you change a hashed password using asp.net membership provider if you don't know the current password?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Problem, there's no method:

```
bool ChangePassword(string newPassword);
```

You have to know the current password (which is probably hashed and forgotten).

Comment: you should separate out your question and add an answer.

Comment: @mcqwerty, now we've separated your answer, you should "accept" your own answer

Comment: Nice job, I did this with our version of the ChangePassword control (Admin changing password for users) ;)

Comment: Come on one more up votes he gets a badge ...

Comment: @harriyott You can't accept your own answer last time I tried.

Comment: @CheGueVerra: Better late than never :-)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This is an easy one that I wasted too much time on. Hopefully this post saves someone else the pain of slapping their forehead as hard as I did.

Solution, reset the password randomly and pass that into the change method.

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();
u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), "myAwesomePassword");
```

Comment: Hey, come on. Don't downvote for answering your own question. The FAQ encourages that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119658

Comment: The down-vote (not me!) was before the answer was moved here. Previously it said that the answer was in the question. I'm not too keen on down-voting people who have only just joined SO - it's much better to edit to help out.

Comment: Yes and he gets the pretty badge too !!

Comment: @harriyott doh... I think next time one of us should leave a comment indicating we're editing... so we don't waste time doing the same thing.

Comment: On my app i get this: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: passwordAnswer

any ideas??

Comment: Make sure you have this attribute set in your web.config if you get the error above:

requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"

Comment: I wasted a lot of time before I found this answer, thank you.

Comment: Can you use this with a textbox? I have been trying and can't get it to work for me

Comment: +1 - kudos; went round the houses on using Membership.ChangePawword() on this too and then found this wee gem.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to change the password if the requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"

I got the work around for this

Created two membership providers in web.config

i am using the AspNetSqlMembershipProviderReset provider for reseting the password since it has the requiresQuestionAndAnswer= false where as AspNetSqlMembershipProvider is the default provider used.

i wrote the following code to reset the password for the user.

public bool ResetUserPassword(String psUserName, String psNewPassword)
    {
        try
        {
           // Get Membership user details using secound membership provider with required question answer set to false.

```
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProviderReset"].GetUser(psUserName,false);

        //Reset the user password.
        String vsResetPassword = currentUser.ResetPassword();            

        //Change the User password with the required password            
        currentUser.ChangePassword(vsResetPassword, psNewPassword);
        //Changed the comments to to force the user to change the password on next login attempt
        currentUser.Comment = "CHANGEPASS";
        //Check if the user is locked out and if yes unlock the user
        if (currentUser.IsLockedOut == true)
        {
            currentUser.UnlockUser();
        }
        Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProviderReset"].UpdateUser(currentUser);            return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        return false;
    }
}
```