# How can i change or update password in asp.net membership via sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership, password-recovery

I have to change a password to something else, I have got all the details like `userid`, `username`, `encrypted password`, `password format`.

How can I change the password via SQL in asp.net membership?

Comment: Check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287320/how-do-you-change-a-hashed-password-using-asp-net-membership-provider-if-you-don

Comment: @E.J.Brennan the post you are referring to, is about resetting the password with C# code, not in SQL.

Answer (score 42):

You can use this query;

```
Declare @UserName NVarChar(30)    
Declare @Password NVarChar(30)    
Declare @Application NVarChar(255)    
Declare @PasswordSalt NVarChar(128)    

set @UserName = 'UserName'    
set @Password = 'Pass'    
set @Application = '/Application'    
Set @PasswordSalt = (SELECT TOP 1 PasswordSalt FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID IN    (SELECT UserID FROM aspnet_Users u, aspnet_Applications a WHERE u.UserName=@UserName and a.ApplicationName = @Application AND u.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId))    

Exec dbo.aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword @Application, @UserName, @Password, 10, 10, @PasswordSalt, -5
```

Comment: This worked great - solves an inherited problem I've had for over 2 years!

Comment: Please note this answer updates the user's password to a plain text password. This will not store a salted and hashed password.  Note that the `set @PasswordSalt` statement does nothing here (and should read Select top 1 PasswordSalt FROM ....).

Comment: How can you make it to encrypt it?

Comment: My aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword  requires 6 instead of 7 parameters: @application, @username, @newPassword, @passwordSalt, @currentTimeUtc, @passwordFormat. So can you explain the 10,10 and the -5? because passwordFormat seems to be always `1`

Comment: Never mind, I was looking at `aspnet_Membership_SetPassword` instead of `aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword`. My bad.