# Is it possible to have full access to sql membership provider from wcf service or desktop application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, membership-provider

I am creating a WCF service that uses an asp.net SQL membership provider to authenticate users. I know that the users can be authenticated with no problems but what about if I wanted to allow users to sign up or change their passwords? Would I be able to access the methods to that provide that functionality of the membership provider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change a hashed password using asp.net membership provider if you don't know the current password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287320/how-do-you-change-a-hashed-password-using-asp-net-membership-provider-if-you-don)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you just have to make sure that you set up the config file to allow that. Then just create your methods to do what you need. [Web.config setup for membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx)

```
public string ChangePassword(string NewPassword)
{
    MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();

    if (u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), NewPassword))
    {
          return "Password changed.";
    }
}
```